# No quick text yet!

Tags: quick-text

I've created some quick text, which works fine when I go to the tasks tab and click into a task record.

However when I go to an Opportunity record, then in the Activities component, if I click the text bubble icon next to the field, then it can't find my quick texts.

The folder is shared with myself and org-wide default on Quick Text is public. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you System Admin ?

Comment: Yep - logged in as System Admin. If I'm on a New Task record by clicking New Task from the Tasks list view, then it works fine - seems that it doesn't work from the Activity component when choosing to create a task

Answer (score 1):

I created a Quick Text as a System Admin with all the permission that you have provided. And when checked , it is displaying for the Log a call Action under Opportunity Object  . [image: Log a Call]

If you go through this article also [Insert and Use Quick Text](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.quick_text_insert.htm&type=5)

It has mentioned the supported fields where you can insert the Quick Text.

[image]

Hope this Helps !

Comment: If I go to the To Do List from the console bar at the bottom of the page, then click the Create Task button, it shows up there. But it doesn't show up from the Comments box when I create a new task from the Activities component. Do you know of any settings that could prevent this from working?